# How to remove CSS class in Wordpress theme for smaller screens

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to remove a CSS class in Wordpress for smaller screens. I tried using visibiliy:hidden in the media queries for max-height 480px for that class but it's not working. Please see http://kingsmanarms.us/. There is a spacer placed above the Classes image with a padding of 235px needed for desktop, but the spacer is creating a padding over the Classes image but the same spacer padding is not creating in issue over the Services image for mobile device

Answer (score 0):

Well I suppose you need something like this:

```css
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #panel-8-0-2-0 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: perfect thanks alfredohb.q! I was targeting the wrong class :)